# JSP Group Items

Tags: java, jsp

i've a webfrontend which displays log events. the events are stored in a h2 database. i don't use any frameworks, just plain jsp / servlet / DAO.

so i've the following class

```
public class Event{ 
 private String date;
 private String event;
 private String hostname; 
 [..]
 }
```

(date is a String but could be anything, that is not the problem)

Build instances of it through my DAO class

```
con = dataSource.getConnection();
stmt = con.createStatement();
String SQL = "Select * from ...";
rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

while(rs.next()) {
   Event event = new Event();
            event.set....
```

and finally display it via JSP

```
<c:forEach var="event" items="${events}">
${event.date} ${event.event} ${event.hostname}    <br>   
</c:forEach>
```

### Now my problem.

I'm trying to group those events by date. so it would look something like this in the jsp part

```
<c:forEach var="event_date" items="${event_dates}">
  ${event_date} <br>
    <c:forEach var="event" items="${event_date.events}">
      ${event.event}  ${event.hostname}  <br>    
    </c:forEach>     
</c:forEach>
```

my approach would be, adding a new EventDates Class containing

```
public class EventDates{    
 private String date;
 private List<Event> events;
 }
```

extend my DAO with another select (select * .. group by date) loop through, create an EventDates instance for each result line, select all events for that specific date (select * from ... where date = ...) and put those results in my List property.

but somehow, this looks and feels way to complicated and one might say it is just wrong! :-)

but i'm not an profession object orient programmer so that's all i can think of. is there a better approach? :-)

thank you!

Comment: List<EventDates> (with internal List) ... seems good (at short reflection)

Answer (score 0):

In real world web application, the database is often a bottleneck, so I would not change (too much) the DAO. I would just ensure that the events are correctly sorted with an `ORDER BY date, ...` clause in the select statement.

Then I would post-process that list of event to build a 2 stage list of lists of events grouped by date, in the service layer. More of less:

```
List<EventDates> eventDates = new ArrayList<>()
EventDates eventDate = new EventDates();  // eventDate.date should be null
for(Event event: eventList) {
    if (! event.date.equals(eventDate.date)) {
        eventDate = new EventDates();
        eventDate.date = event.date;
        /* or if you want to recycle eventDate:
        eventDate.date = event.date;
        eventDate.events = new ArrayList<Event>();
        */
    }
    eventDate.events.add(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a map of events by dates and add it to your model:

   ```
       Map<String, List<Event>> eventMap = events.stream()
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Event::getDate));
   ```
2. Iterate over the map in the following way:

   ```
   <c:forEach items="${eventMap}" var="eventEntry">
       <c:out value="${eventEntry.key}"/>
       </br>
       <c:forEach items="${eventEntry.value}" varStatus="loopStatus" var="event">
           <c:out value="Event #${loopStatus.index} ${event.event}"/>
           </br>
       </c:forEach>
   </c:forEach>
   ```